# AngularJS radiobutton change event stops working

Tags: angularjs

I have a set of radiobuttons displayed and would like to track the selected index based on user input but for some reason with Angular - after a few clicks the change event stops working. Any ideas why?

I have a list in scope and a div which displays everything correctly:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="user in users">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sproket/8Wtu6/

If you're using firefox I have the console enabled.

Comment: Post your code as well so as to maintain this question in totum within SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function only fires once for each radiobutton, if you change ng-change to ng-click, it fires all the time:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio{{$index}}" name="chkUserName" value="{{$index}}" ng-model="selectedUser" ng-click='selectUser(selectedUser)'>
```

But even better would be to skip the click event completely and bind directly to the model like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
  Selected user: {{model.selectedUser}}

        <div data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            <input type="radio" id="radio{{$index}}" 
               name="chkUserName" value="{{$index}}"
               ng-model="model.selectedUser">
            <label for="radio{{$index}}">{{user.name}}</label>
        </div>    

</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    console.log("MyCtrl")
    $scope.name = 'BLAH';

     var users = [{
        name: "SUPPORT, User",
        code: "support"
    }, {
        name: "Test, Radiologist ",
        code: "rtest"
    }, {
        name: "Test, Physician",
        code: "ptest"
    }, {
        name: "TEST, CLERK ",
        code: "ctest"
    }, {
        name: "Test, Transcriptionist",
        code: "ytest"
    }];
    $scope.users = users;
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.model.selectedUser = 0;

}
```

No need to capture click or change events!

Comment: You're welcome. If you use the $parent contruction suggested in the accepted answer, you don't need the event capturing either. So I would say that is the best answer indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead:

```
ng-model="selectedUser"
```

Write:

```
ng-model="$parent.selectedUser"
```

Fixed Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wtu6/16/)**</kbd>

---

In `ng-repeat` directive each element  has own scope (you might call it *isolate* scope) and therefore in your example `ngModel` it's locked. To use `ngModel` *outside* add `$parent` prefix

Comment: That's neat but I don't get how that fixes the issue. How does parent make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Change ng-change to ng-click.  ng-change is remembering your previous answers.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonesmac82/376SS/1/

```
<input type="radio" id="radio{{$index}}" name="chkUserName" value="{{$index}}" ng-model="selectedUser" ng-click='selectUser(selectedUser)'>
```